# Customised query to display in CGridView in yii

Tags: yii-extensions, yii, yii-components, yii-events

Controller,

```
    $model=Product::model()->display_products_statistics();
$this->render('admin',array(
    'model'=>$model,
));
```

View,

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'product-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->display_products_statistics(),
'filter'=> $model,
'columns'=> array(
    'member_count',
    'seller_count',
    'visitor_count',
    'lowest price',
    'desc',
    'price',
    'createdate',
    'updatedate',
    'opid',
    'pimg',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
     ));
```

Model,

```
$sql="select member_count,seller_count,
visitor_count from fc_product fp
group by  member_count,visitor_count,seller_count
order by member_count desc";
$connection=Yii::app()->db;
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
$products_statistics=$command->queryAll();
$dataprovider=new CArrayDataProvider($products_statistics,
    array('pagination'=>false));
return $dataprovider->getData();
```

But then I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in                         D:\wamp\www\yii\framework\zii\widgets\CBaseListView.php on line 111

I am confused and don't know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not using CDataProvider in the correct way. CGridView needs an instance of CDataProvider to display, but you have used CDataProvider->getData() instead. I'd also recommend using CSqlDataProvider, which is purpose made for custom sql queries. Try this in your model;

```
$count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fc_product')->queryScalar();
$sql="select member_count,seller_count,
visitor_count from fc_product fp
group by  member_count,visitor_count,seller_count
order by member_count desc";
return new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
    'totalItemCount' => $count,
    'sort' => array(
        'attributes' => array(
             'member_count', 'visitor_count', 'seller_count',
        ),
    ),
    'pagination' => false
```